# JSF PrimeFaces Removing pageLinks

Tags: html, jsf-2, primefaces

My tasks is to create pager, what I've already done, but I stuck at one point,

I need to hide pageLinks ( Small boxes that indixe on which page you are ) and leave only "arrows" to move between pages.

```
<p:dataTable value= "#{inboxController.list}" var="task"

paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" pageLinks="0"

rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,25,30,50" rows="20"

lazy="true">`
```

So as you can see, I used `pageLinks="0"`  which sets up, how many page box'es I want to show, and it does, what I want, until I move to another page and all boxes shows up again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this... somehow I find out answer by my self..

Maybe it will be usefull for someone else..

so all I did is :

```
paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">
```

Comment: Like can be found in the PrimeFaces documentation!